# How to create association in factory_girl, rspec/rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using rspec and factory girl to develop an application which has users and each user has many media post. To go with TDD I'm using factory_girl.

After setting up the application, I got two files in spec/factories:

users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:first_name) {|n| "FirstName-#{n}"}
    sequence(:last_name) {|n| "LastName-#{n}"}
    sequence(:email) {|n| "email-#{n}@example.com"}
    password 'chandan123'
    password_confirmation 'chandan123'
  end
end
```

And the medias.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :media do
    sequence(:description) {|n| "Description #{n}"}
    sequence(:url) {|n| "http://www.example-#{n}.com"}
    association :user, factory: :user

    factory :public_media do
      permission Media.permissions[:is_public]
    end

    factory :private_media do
      permission Media.permissions[:is_private]
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when I run rspec, I'm getting following error:

```
$ rspec


Finished in 0.08492 seconds (files took 3.21 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures

/Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing': undefined method `user=' for #<Media:0x007fb5d0b57b50> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/build.rb:9:in `result'
    from /Users/chandankumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
```

My query is, why its not able to recognise user factory? Why I'm getting above exception.

### UPDATE:

I had to add migration to do association at database/model level. Once that's done it worked out perfectly. My bad, I was under impression that rspec will give me failure message instead of exception.

Comment: Could you add the code of both your models of `Media` and `User` for clarity?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PawełDawczak. You indirectly pointed me to solution. I expected a failure instead of exception while doing TDD. Is that a expected behavior to get exception instead of failure message?

Comment: To be honest - I'm not sure in which way it would fail with factories, because every time, before defining factories, I'm test-driving my model first - please check the answer! Good luck!

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for suggesting the right approach. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were test drive the `Media` model - I'd rather try to implement proper methods before defining factories. So, I'd start with something like:

*spec/models/media_spec.rb*

```
RSpec.describe Media do
  subject { Media.new }

  # ...

  it { is_expected.to respond_to :user }
end
```

When running your tests, this will drive you to creating proper association in `Media`:

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

After fulfilling this requirement, I would provide sufficient *factories* based on functionality we have, thus mentioned exception would not be thrown.